# objective zip not working with audio files and not compressing existing directories

Tags: objective-c, zlib

i'm using objective-zip for compressing audio files into a zip file but when i make that this exception appears to me:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'ZipException', reason: 
'Error in opening '/Users/macuser/Library/Application 
Support/iPhoneSimulator/5.1/Applications/79E57C84-3B47-437C-BB44- 
89BAAB034DF5/Documents/ADDRecordFileForTest_0_07-05-2012 12:42:45.caf' in zipfile
```

also i tried to first put all my audio files into one directory and then use objective-zip to compress these directory but the exception below also arrises:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'ZipException', reason: 
'Can't open '/Users/macuser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/
Applications/79E57C84-3B47-437C-BB44-89BAAB034DF5/Documents/
CurrentMeeting_AudioFiles
```

is objective-zip supports only text files, why objective-zip doesn't compress existing folders? any help is welcomed,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Colons in filenames can cause problems.

```
ADDRecordFileForTest_0_07-05-2012 12:42:45.caf
```

Consider using dashes. I wouldn't use spaces as well. At least as long as you don't have to work on filenames created by users (for convenience / user-experience).

Further more zip usually does not keep directories. If you zip a file within a folder, though, the directory is part of the path. I didn't use Objective-Zip, yet - will try though, as ZipArchive currently doesn't work for me, as I need it. I wrote a "zip -r" category for ZipArchive, that basically works like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)directoriesAndFilesAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError *fileManagerError = nil;
    NSArray *directoryContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&fileManagerError];
    if (!directoryContents) {
        *error = fileManagerError;
        return nil;
    }

    BOOL isDir;
    NSMutableArray *dirs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    NSMutableArray *files = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
    for (NSString *object in directoryContents) {
        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:object] isDirectory:&isDir]) {
            if (isDir) {
                [dirs addObject:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:object]];
            } else {
                [files addObject:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:object]];
            }
        }
    }

    return @{kDirectoriesKey: dirs, kFilesKey: files};
}
```

You can then use a recursive method adding the files to the zip and call itself for each directory.